# More efficient way to do this search algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, search

I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this algorithm. I find I need to do this type of operation pretty often, and the way I am currently doing it takes hours since I believe it would be considered an n^2 algorithm. I'll attach it below.

```
import csv

with open("location1", 'r') as main:
    csvMain = csv.reader(main)
    mainList = list(csvMain)

with open("location2", 'r') as anno:
    csvAnno = csv.reader(anno)
    annoList = list(csvAnno)

tempList = []
output = []

for full in mainList:
    geneName = full[2].lower()
    for annot in annoList:
        if geneName == annot[2].lower():
            tempList.extend(full)
            tempList.append(annot[3])
            tempList.append(annot[4])
            tempList.append(annot[5])
            tempList.append(annot[6])
            output.append(tempList)

        for i in tempList:
            del i

with open("location3", 'w') as final:
    a = csv.writer(final, delimiter=',')
    a.writerows(output)
```

I have two csv files containing 15,000 strings each, and I am looking to compare columns from each, and if they match, concatenate the end of the second csv to the end of the first. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Pro: Works with native libraries and has no external dependencies.  Con: You can probably do it much easier and much faster with Pandas (as mentioned below).  Both, comparison and appending (I think it would be 3 or 4 lines of code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be more efficient this way:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open("location1", 'r') as main:
  csvMain = csv.reader(main)
  mainList = list(csvMain)

with open("location2", 'r') as anno:
  csvAnno = csv.reader(anno)
  annoList = list(csvAnno)

output = []
annoMap = defaultdict(list)

for annot in annoList:
  tempList = annot[3:]  # adapt this to the needed columns
  annoMap[annot[2].lower()].append(tempList)  # put these columns into the map at position of the column of intereset

for full in mainList:
  geneName = full[2].lower()
  if geneName in annoMap:  # check if matching column exists
    output.extend(annoMap[geneName])

with open("location3", 'w') as final:
  a = csv.writer(final, delimiter=',')
  a.writerows(output)
```

It is more efficient since you need to iterate over each list just once. The lookup in the dictionary is O(1) on average so you basically get a linear algorithm.

Comment: It might help if you explain *why* your changes make it more efficient.

Comment: Beautiful! This was almost perfect, although it only prints out the mapped values to the file. It was an easy fix to append both the *full* variable along with the *annoMap[geneName]* to make one long string. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to use a library like [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). the built-in functions are pretty efficient.

You can load your csv into dataframe with `pandas.read_csv()` and then manipulate them with pandas functions.

For example you can use `Pandas.merge()` to merge the two dataframe (aka your two csv files) on a particular column and then drop the one you don't need.

If you have some database knowledge, the logic is quite similar here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @limes for the help. This was the final script I used, thought I would post it to help others. Thanks again!

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open("location1", 'r') as main:
  csvMain = csv.reader(main)
  mainList = list(csvMain)

with open("location2", 'r') as anno:
  csvAnno = csv.reader(anno)
  annoList = list(csvAnno)

output = []
annoMap = defaultdict(list)

for annot in annoList:
  tempList = annot[3:]  # adapt this to the needed columns
  annoMap[annot[2].lower()].append(tempList)  # put these columns into the map at position of the column of intereset

for full in mainList:
  geneName = full[2].lower()
  if geneName in annoMap:  # check if matching column exists
    list = annoMap[geneName]
    full.extend(list[0])
    output.append(full)

with open("location3", 'w') as final:
 a = csv.writer(final, delimiter=',')
 a.writerows(output)
```